# What is dictionary filter in Impala?

Tags: database, dictionary, filtering, encode, impala

I find there is dictionary filter in Impala when doing Parquet scan. The comment says the column is 100% dictionary encoded can be dictionary filtered. What kind of columns can be dictionary encoded? And is there any example of dictionary filter? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary size per row group has an uplimit, which is 40000 for impala < 2.9. So it is related to the cardinality of the encoded column. Basically if there are many different strings in one row group, the dictionary encoding won't be 100%. You can further refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encodings.md)